# Area between curves using integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area

Okay so I have to find the area bounded by $y= x^2-3x+2,x=1,x=2$ and $y=0$

I sketched the graphs and tried to solved it like this

[image]

Okay so I took the integral for the quadratic from $x=1$ to $x=2$ which should give me the area of the curved part (which is the required answer) plus all the area above x axis and in between $x=1$ to $x=2$. I know I need to subtract this second area but don't know how. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to tell sideways, but it looks like you forgot to divide by $3$ in the first anti-derivative.

Comment: Yes rightly said I saw it now. Stupid mistake. And thank you all friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just inspecting it,

[image]

it seems like this simplifies to 
$$
\left| \int_{1}^{2}x^2-3x+2 \ dx \right|
$$
$$
=  \left| \left[ \frac{1}{3}x^3 -\frac{3}{2}x^2+2x   \right]_{1}^{2} \right|
$$
$$
= \left|  \left( 
\frac{(2)^3}{3}-\frac{3(2)^2}{2}+2(2)\right)-\left(\frac{(1)^3}{3}-\frac{3(1)^2}{2}+2(1)\right) \right|
$$

Comment: Brother what app do you use specifically to sketch these graphs?

Comment: @Zlatan Desmos online calculator.  It's great.  Hear's the graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/egwlyidxma

Comment: Alright. Lol bro you're just solving the whole integral step by step. That's great but I already got the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Carser +1 and next +1 in mind for the calculator. :-)

Comment: Just an obvious question, do you think this question deserves an upvote?

Comment: Lol @Zlatan sure, especially if you fix your image!

Comment: @Carser  bro I can't, I took it like that from my phone so, nevermind the upvote. I upvoted for you though, don't know it will show now or not but I did and I accepted your answer. Cheers mate. In future if I have to request any answer from a particular user or expert like you then what should I do?

Comment: Oh @Zlatan you can have my +1.  I'm not sure, but maybe you can tag a user in comments, and maybe that works to notify them.

Comment: How to do it @bfam?

Comment: Yeah, like that.  And I fixed your image.

Comment: Please be more careful [reviewing bogus edits.](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/683791)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Area=$\int_{a}^{b} (u(x)-l(x))\,dx$, where $u$ is the upper and $l$ is the lower function. In your case $u(x)=0$ on $[1,2]$.

(Rotating of  your picture is probably an easy method to see limits of interval and the limiting functions.)

Comment: Hey thanks for the help and can you offer me any advice about closing down a question?

Comment: @Zlatan I would suggest not to close your question. Carser's answer may be useful for future users.

Comment: Okay I won't close the question but still if I wanted to then how could I possibly do it?

Comment: @Zlatan You are probably thinking not about closing (making inactive) but deleting your question. You have gray `delete` under your question. I am not sure if always or some level of reputation is needed.